# Adjust size of iFrame when the content expands

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iFrame displaying content pulled in from a separate service. However, the content has a button that loads more content horizontally, via AJAX, and pushes the height of the content down, causing scrollbars.

Is there any way to get the iFrame to respond to this change, and increase its height when the user loads more content inside?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this microsoft article might have your answer:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278469

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>
<!--
function reSize()
{
    try{    
    var oBody   =   ifrm.document.body;
    var oFrame  =   document.all("ifrm");

    oFrame.style.height = oBody.scrollHeight + (oBody.offsetHeight - oBody.clientHeight);
    oFrame.style.width = oBody.scrollWidth + (oBody.offsetWidth - oBody.clientWidth);
    }
    //An error is raised if the IFrame domain != its container's domain
    catch(e)
    {
    window.status = 'Error: ' + e.number + '; ' + e.description;
    }
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload=reSize()>
    <iframe onresize=reSize() id=ifrm src=YOUR_PAGE_HERE></iframe>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Basically, tap into the resize event of the child document, and resize your iframe accordingly.